# val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-notifications, builder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCkRe.png)

i try to write this line , then it will shows an erreo what is the solution for that error pleas help my i am fully stuck on that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG3Tn.png)

Comment: I also add the  image of that error please help me

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an integer for channelId argument, try use a String or Notification.

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#Builder(android.content.Context,java.lang.String)